# Computer guesses your number (has to be in 10 tries) from 1-1000

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, organization

OK, to start off I am a complete beginner in a computer science class. I could ask my teacher, but I don't have time to do so. So, expect some really dumb errors that I can't see and I am using eclipse.

here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int something()
{
    int big = 1000;//largest number is 1000
    int small = 1;//smallest number is 1

    //so, best guess is to go in the middle
    int c;//my guesses
    int inequality;//used to write if statements

    for (int a = 0; a <= 10; a++)
    {
        cout << "Think about a number between 1-1000" << endl;//what console tells you
        c = (big - small) / 2;//my guess will be the midpoint of the two numbers
        while (big > small)//while the highest number is ALWAYS greater than the lowest number
        {
            cout << "Is your number less than, equal to, or greater than my guess? 1-less,2-equal,3-greater" << c << endl;
            cin >> inequality;//you tell me whether my guess is too high, low, or equal
            if (inequality == 1)//if you say it is too low...
            {
                small = c;//the smallest number is now my last guess
                c = c - (big - small) / 2;//so, I'll take the midpoint of the CURRENT biggest and smallest number
            }
            else if (inequality == 2)//if you say it is equal...
            {
                cout << "Yay, I guessed your number." << endl;//cool.
            }
            else if (inequality == 3)//if you say it is too high...
            {
                big = c;//biggest number is now my guess
                c = c + (big - small) / 2;//so, I'll take the midpoint of the CURRENT biggest and smallest number
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;//returns something in int main function
}

int main()
{
    something();//so I can actually do code.
}
```

So my problem:

If I enter 1 after the console enters the first guess, I get 499, which is fine. After the second guess (where I enter 1), I get 249, which is also fine. However, the third guess after I enter 1 gets a random 681, so could someone help me?

It would be most appreciated if you **did not rewrite the entire code for me, otherwise that is really suspicious when I turn it in.** I am struggling because I do not have very good computer science background, so to improve, I need ideas mostly. Lastly, any way to make my code look a LITTLE more professional would be appreciated :)

Also, my for loop may be a bit off, I'm not sure.

Comment: Why are you adding the `c+` and `c -` terms to your midpoint calculations?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program?  Eclipse probably has a graphical frontend to your toolchain, but if you can't figure it out you can add prints to trace your local variables.

Comment: @jkeys: well, I tried binary search to solve this problem, and so I used the guess as the new smallest number when the user pressed 1. then, the consul would take that new smallest number and subtract it from the difference of the biggest number and new smallest number, which would be binary search.
Sorry, my wording is confusing, want me to restate that, or can you understand it?

Comment: Also, you're (probably) not getting 681. You're getting -681. This is because `int`s can go below 0. Think of why that could happen.

Comment: @chipster the number is not too low, (sorry wording was REALLY confusing) but the user typing 1 meant that the guess was lower, so yeah; I need to go lower

Comment: @user12280248 Oh, got you. Sorry, that was also probably partly my bad too.

Comment: @chipster great point, I couldn't see that. (also, 126 is also negative)
and to your question, I know that integers can contain negatives, however when I thought of my code (using flowchart) I got it summarized as that my code should always be using binary search.
so in short, no, I don't know. (unnecessary info)

Comment: @user12280248 Not sure why you would need a binary search tree here, but I didn't retain a lot of information on them from school. Anyway, my point is that there is something you're doing wrong to `c` that is making it go negative. Figure that part out and you've solved your problem. Think about it (because it will be helpful for you in the long run if you try yourself first), but then if you're still in the dark have a look at Anders' answer and it should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you calculate next number you need to change range

So you have first

```
small     guess     big
+---------+----------+
```

if user says too small, then the answer is above the guess, so in the range
`big - guess` and that is what you need to cut in half so instead of

```
c = c - (big - small)/2

guess = (big - guess) / 2 + guess
```

if user says too big then the answer is between guess and small

```
guess = (guess - small) / 2 + small
```

Comment: He is changing range by doing `small = c` or `big = c` respectively. Maybe I'm missing something obvious but I think your formula is incorrect.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKS!!!
@jkeys he is, ( because my wording is really incorrect); I fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `c+` and `c -` terms from your midpoint calculations.

Edit: Also, try swapping the `small = c` and `big = c` statements in the two conditionals.

Your comments are mostly incorrect and that was my source of confusion.

Comment: First off, can you please explain why? Im beginner, so things obvious to you are not obvious to me :|
Secondly, I tried and got a different error, where the third time
(after pressing 1) got 375.

Comment: @user12280248 because the number line is one dimensional, the midpoint formula is simply `(x1 + x2) / 2`. Can you please explain why you're adding or subtracting the original guess from your new guess?

Comment: @user12280248 also how do you know 375 is incorrect? what is the number you had in mind? xD

Comment: because here's how it went:
I press 1, consul returns 499
I then press 1, consul returns 249
I press one again, expecting a lower number, but get 375. that's why